# Extract names and email addresses form a text

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract names and email addresses from a list of emails in this format:

```
...
Sent: 19 July 2019 14:25
To: John Dough <john@dough.zzz>
...
```

This extracts email addresses perfectly:

```
/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i
```

How can I also get the string between `To:` and `<` example: `John Dough` ?

Comment: How do you expect it to differentiate between "Hello World" (not a name?) and "John Smith" (name)? What is your definition of a "name"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo might use 2 capturing groups (assuming the name part can not contain characters `<` and `>` If those chars can occur, you could use a non greedy quantifier `(.*?)` instead of `([^<>]+)`

```
\bTo: ([^<>\r\n]+) <([a-z0-9_+.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8G3z7p/1)

*About `([^<>\r\n]+)`*

- `(` Capture group

  - `[^<>\r\n]+` Negated character class, match 1+ times any char except `<` `>` or a newline
- `)` Close group

Or make the match a bit broader matching a non whitespace char except an @

```
\bTo: ([^<>\r\n]+) <([^\s@]+@[^\s@]+)>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pgrk6j/1)

Comment: There is a problem when the `<email@address.com>` part is missing after `To: Name Here`.  https://regex101.com/r/wRKF19/2

Comment: @sanchez You can exclude matching a newline https://regex101.com/r/8G3z7p/1 I have updated the anwer.